# Keep getting the same error message, can't multiply sequence by non-int of type float

Tags: python

I am trying to return the value of the horizontal component of force based on the user's inputs, and I have this, but keep getting the same error message that I 'can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'', and have run out of ideas as to what is wrong with it.

```
from math import sin, cos, pi, sqrt, radians
F = input('Enter your Force')
theta = input('Enter your angle')
F = float(F)
theta = radians(float(theta))

def find_hforce(F, theta):
if F != '' and theta != '':
    Fhorizontal = float(F*cos(theta))
    equationFhorizontal = 'Fcos(',theta,')'
else:
    Fhorizontal = ''
return (equationFhorizontal, Fhorizontal)

if unknown == 'horizontal force':
equationFhorizontal, Fhorizontal = find_hforce(F, theta)
    if Fhorizontal != '':
        print ('The horizontal component of force is:', Fhorizontal, 'N')
        print ('The equation you needed to use is:', equationFhorizontal)
```

Comment: provide complete error message

Comment: what is `unknown`, which line in the error?

Comment: your code intentation is off, please fix it. indent your method bodys. why are you comparing your floats/radians to empty strings? thats always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work:

```
from math import sin, cos, pi, sqrt, radians

def find_hforce(F, theta):
    if isinstance(F,float) and isinstance(theta,float):
        Fhorizontal = float(F*cos(theta))
        equationFhorizontal = 'Fcos('+str(theta)+')'
    else:
        Fhorizontal = ''
    return (equationFhorizontal, Fhorizontal)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    F = input('Enter your Force')
    theta = input('Enter your angle')
    F = float(F)
    theta = radians(float(theta))

    equationFhorizontal, Fhorizontal = find_hforce(F, theta)
    if Fhorizontal != '':
        print ('The horizontal component of force is:', Fhorizontal, 'N')
        print ('The equation you needed to use is:', equationFhorizontal)
```

Comments: I could not reproduce your problem. In anycase the [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) method lets you check if a variable has a certain type. But that is not necessary since you already changed the type after the input. If somebody would type a letter for example it will raise a `ValueError` which you should catch. How to do this is explained here:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html